# How to flatten tuples inside a group bag

Tags: apache-pig

Suppose we have the following data in `test_file`:

```
1, 3, 4
1, 5, 6
```

and the following script:

```
r1 = load 'test_file' using PigStorage(',') as (a:int, b:int, c:int);

r2 = foreach r1 generate a, (b, c) as bc;

r2_group = group r2 by a;

r3 = foreach r2_group generate group as a, r2.bc as bc;
```

The `r3` will look like the following:

```
(1, {((3, 4)), ((5,6))})
```

So, how can I modify above script to produce something like below?

```
(1, ((3,4), (5,6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following code does the trick:

```
r4 = foreach r3 {
    tmp = BagToTuple(bc);
    generate a as a,
        tmp as bc;
}
```

The `r4` will look like below:

```
(1,((5,6),(3,4)))
```